# Moodle: open course with a link

Tags: moodle

Is there a feature in moodle that allows users (users that have an access, not guest) to enter the course with a link shared by admin?

What I want is that when a user clicks on that link, a login page appears, after logging in, the user is automatically enrolled in that course.

Moodle version: 3.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the need of coding, you could enable the self-enrol enrolment method at course level with enrolment key (defaulting to student role), then provide the link to the course to the existing user you wish he/she self-enrolls as student.

The user, once logged in and trying to access the course, will be presented with a form requesting the enrolment key, once the correct key is provided he/she will be self-enrolled as student.

If you want something more direct, like a token based kind of direct authentication+enrol you will need to use an existing plugin (like this one https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_enrolkey) or write your own.

Comment: great, this is the answer i've been looking for. thanks~